# Get column names in order in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting all the column names in a table using:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME='<TABLE_NAME>' 
AND OWNER = '<SCHEMA>'
```

I am calling this same sql statment on an identical table in a different database, but getting the results in a different order. Is there something I can append to my sql such that the columns will be returned in the same order?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Assuming your tables really are identical with columns defined in the same order in both databases, you can order by `COLUMN_ID` to ensure consistent ordering.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME='<TABLE_NAME>' 
AND OWNER = '<SCHEMA>'
ORDER BY COLUMN_ID
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to guarantee that the columns are listed in the same order regardless of the order in which they were defined, sort by the column name:

```
...
ORDER BY column_name
```